# SQL Date as INT to Date for Query

Tags: sql-server-2012, datetime-format

I have a query built on the msdb..sysjobhistory table the MSDB database of my SQL Server.  I want to be able to only give me back the stuff with the previous date. (in this example, 1/14/2015 would be yesterday) How do I go about this when the **run_date** information is in YYYYMMDD Integer format?

```
SELECT  server
        , jh.run_date
        , jh.run_time
        , j.name
        , jh.run_duration 
        , jh.step_name
        , run_status
        , message
FROM    msdb..sysjobhistory jh
INNER JOIN msdb..sysjobs j ON jh.job_id = j.job_id 
WHERE   jh.step_id = 0
```

Please advise.

-Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try converting that INT first to a VARCHAR and then using the 112 "Style" (noted on the MSDN page for [Cast and Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)), convert that to a real DATETIME. For example:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 20150115), 112)
```

Of course, doing that alone would invalidate an index on the `[run_date]` field, if there is one.  If that is the case, then you can just do the DATEADD to substract a day and then convert back to VARCHAR and then to INT. For example:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(INT,
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 
                       DATEADD(DAY,
                               -1,
                               CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 20150115), 112)
                              ),
                        112
                      )
              );
```

On my SQL Server 2012 instance there is no index on `[run_date]`, but might be best to still not wrap a field around a function.

If just using a `DATETIME` value, such as provided by `GETDATE()`, it would look like:

```sql
WHERE   jh.step_id = 0
AND     jh.run_date = CONVERT(INT,
                              CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
                                      DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()),
                                      112)
                             )
```

Comment: That gives me what I need.  I'm simply grabbing this data to feed into a database I'm creating for an internal DBA Audit application I'm working on.  This worked beautifully.  Thank you, @srutzky !

Comment: @NCollinsTE no problem. Be sure to see the updates I just posted.